# Affection of a string error Scilab

Tags: scilab

I am trying to print out a simple output table in scilab that is just a matrix of numbers with a top row of headers.The issue that arises is I don't know how to print strings in just the top row of an initialized matrix.
For example,

```
 b= ['i', 'j']
```

prints

```
!i j!
```

with exclamation points. What are these exclamation points for?

And

```
b = zeros(m1, m2)
b(1,:) = ['i', 'j' ...]
```

gives an error

```
!--error 10000 
%c_i_s: Affection of a string in a matrix of numbers is not implemented.
```

What is the meaning of this error? How do I otherwise print strings in a matrix but accessing one of the row/columns? I tried putting string(i) but this also did not work.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A Scilab matrix has entries of numeric type. You can't put strings in it. Typically, one keeps header strings separately from data.

```
headers = ['i', 'j', 'k']
data = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

Instead of using `disp`, which formats data in a pre-determined way (in particular, it includes ! delimiters around arrays of strings), use [`mprintf`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/mprintf.html) to format it in your own way. A simple example:

```
mprintf('%s %s %s\n', headers)
mprintf('%d %d %d\n', data)
```

This outputs

```
i j k
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Here is one with more spacing:

```
mprintf('%7s %7s %7s\n', headers)
mprintf('%7d %7d %7d\n', data)
```

Output:

```
  i       j       k
  1       2       3
  4       5       6
  7       8       9
```

See the docs on [formatting parameters](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/printf_conversion.html) for more examples.